# How do I export an object from blender to Unreal Engine 4 correctly?

Tags: objects, export, unreal-engine

Now even though I have an object imported in Blender and one that made myself but I can't seem to export them correctly. And how do I make scales match with those of Unreal Engine 4?

Answer (score 0):

You save your model as Obj or Fbx and import it to your scene. Fbx is more practical for rigged models and I would suggest that you use the TGA file type for textured meshes.